# How to add message that will be read with dmesg?

Tags: linux, syslog, dmesg

I am trying to write some custom messages in my dmesg output. I tried:

```
logger "Hello"
```

but this does not work. It exits without error, but no "Hello" appears int the output of:

```
dmesg
```

I am using a Fedora 9, and it seems that there is no syslogd/klogd daemon running. However, all my kernel messages are succesfully written in the dmesg buffer.

Any idea?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`dmesg` displays what is in the kernel buffer, whereas `logger` is for `syslogd`.  I think if you want to print things into the kernel buffer you will need to create a driver that uses the `printk()` kernel function. If you just want it in `/var/log/messages`, then with a "normal" setup I think what you have done with `logger` is already fine.

The most basic example of a driver with `printk()` would be:

hello.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world\n");

}
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Then:

```
$ make
$ sudo insmod hello.ko
$ dmesg | tail -n1
 [7089996.746366] Hello world
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN121 for more...

Comment: I got an error, since you have put spaces before the `make -C ...` in the Makefile instead of a Tab, so copying the above contents of the Makefile does not work - more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop). I appear to be unable to add this in an edit... Thanks by the way, great answer.

Comment: syslog messages are now in `/var/log/syslog` and not anymore in `/var/log/messages`. (Changed for Ubuntu at least. Other distros might use the old location.)

Comment: Improved version of the driver he wrote can be found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/140354/how-to-add-message-that-will-be-read-with-dmesg/739019#739019

Answer (score 136):

You can, as root, write to `/dev/kmsg` to print to the kernel message buffer:

```
 fixnum:~# echo Some message > /dev/kmsg
 fixnum:~# dmesg | tail -n1
 [28078118.692242] Some message
```

I've tested this on my server and an embedded Linux device, and it works on both, so I'm just going to assume it works pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Interesting that in Ubuntu, this works as root but not with sudo. One actually needs to become root.

Comment: Actually, that's because the input redirection is handled by your shell, which is not running with elevated rights. Try running `echo Some message | sudo tee /dev/kmesg` as non-root.

Comment: That works. Thanks, interesting. By the way, its `kmsg` not `kmesg` but I also confuse with `dmesg` which has the e!

Comment: Much easier than compiling kernel module

Comment: For correct formatting in the syslog, be sure to add a priority (delimited with angles) and a tag (delimited by a colon). `echo '<4>Foo: Message' | sudo tee /dev/kmsg`

Answer (score 14):

Based on Kyle's module above:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

static int pk_write(struct file *file, const char *buffer, unsigned long count, void *data)
{
        char string[256];
        count = count < 255 ? count : 255;

        if(copy_from_user(string, buffer, count))
                return -EFAULT;

        string[count] = '\0';        
        printk(string);
        return count;
}


static int __init printk_init(void)
{
        struct proc_dir_entry *pk_file;

        pk_file = create_proc_entry("printk", 0222, NULL);
        if(pk_file == NULL)
                return -ENOMEM;

        pk_file->write_proc = pk_write;
        pk_file->owner = THIS_MODULE;

        return 0;
}

static void __exit printk_cleanup(void)
{
        remove_proc_entry("printk", NULL);
}

module_init(printk_init);
module_exit(printk_cleanup);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

To do a printk from user space:

```
echo "Hello" > /proc/printk
```

Comment: This works for Linux kernel < 3.10 only. See my answer for a newer alternative.

Answer (score 6):

@Calandoa's answer no longer works for Kernel +3.10. Combined his code, and the example code I found [here](http://tuxthink.blogspot.ca/2013/10/creating-read-write-proc-entry-in.html). Then improved on the code quality...

Code saved to printk_user.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

static ssize_t write_proc(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t count, loff_t *offsetp)
{
    char string[256];
    count = count < 255 ? count : 255;

    if(copy_from_user(string, buffer, count) != 0) {
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    string[count] = '\0';
    printk(string);
    return count;
}

static const struct file_operations proc_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .write = write_proc,
};

static int proc_init(void) {
    struct proc_dir_entry *proc_file;
    proc_file = proc_create("printk_user", 0, NULL, &proc_fops);

    if(proc_file == NULL) {
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void proc_cleanup(void) {
    remove_proc_entry("printk_user", NULL);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); 
module_init(proc_init);
module_exit(proc_cleanup);
```

Make using this Makefile

```
TARGET = printk_user
obj-m := $(TARGET).o
    
KERNEL_VERSION=$(shell uname -r)
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VERSION)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)
    
printk:
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
    
clean:
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

You'll need your current running kernel source code installed in order to make this.
After you run `make` you will need to `sudo insmod printk_user.ko` to load the kernel module.
The module creates `/proc/printk_user`, by default with permissions 444.
If you need all users to access, modify with `sudo chmod 666 /proc/printk_user`

To do a printk from user space:

```
echo "Hello" > /proc/printk_user
```

Sample output:

```
$ dmesg | tail
[13291030.939275] printk_user: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[13291030.939862] printk_user: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[13291103.728306] Hello
```

edit: /proc/printk used to be for Kernel 3/4, but it appears the latest kernel has support for /proc/printk_user

Answer (score 3):

Based off of Kyle's answer, [here](http://www.linuxchix.org/content/courses/kernel_hacking/lesson8) is a quick tutorial showing how to do just that.

Answer (score 3):

Figured I'd go ahead and include a full blown example of something that people can just compile and run for those that aren't as skilled with C based off of @BuvinJ 's answer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // open function
#include <unistd.h> // close function
#include "sys/syscall.h"


int main(); // Let's not worry about this for now

void dmesg( const char *tag, const char *msg, const int len )
{
    const int TAG_LEN=3;
    char buffer[128]={0};
    memcpy( &buffer[0], tag, TAG_LEN );
    memcpy( &buffer[TAG_LEN], msg, len );
    int fd_kmsg = open( "/dev/kmsg", O_WRONLY );
    write( fd_kmsg, &buffer, TAG_LEN+len );
    close( fd_kmsg );
}
void dmesgWarn(  const char *msg, const int len ){ dmesg( "<4>", msg, len ); }
void dmesgInfo(  const char *msg, const int len ){ dmesg( "<6>", msg, len ); }
void dmesgDebug( const char *msg, const int len ){ dmesg( "<7>", msg, len ); }


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int getmysize = strlen(argv[1]);
    printf("%d\n", getmysize);
    
    printf("To be written: %s\nSize of argument: %d\n", argv[1], getmysize);
    // dmesgWarn dmesgInfo or dmesgDebug
    dmesgDebug(argv[1], getmysize);
};
```

To run save the above as ***kmsg.c*** then execute `gcc kmsg.c -o kmsg` and run as `sudo ./kmsg "string you want to add to /dev/kmsg"`

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted some quick debugging messages in a daemon written by someone else in a cross complied kernel. I ran into a compile error trying to use `printk`, as `<linux/module.h>` could not be included.  Rather then battle with that excessively (to do this the right way) I cheated and used the following lazy, but functional 5 minute workaround:

```
void dmesg( const char *tag, const char *msg, const int len )
{
    size_t taglen = strlen(tag);
    char buffer[taglen + len];
    memcpy(&buffer[0], tag, taglen);
    memcpy(&buffer[taglen], msg, len);
    int fd_kmsg = open("/dev/kmsg", O_WRONLY);
    write(fd_kmsg, &buffer, TAG_LEN + len);
    close(fd_kmsg);
}
void dmesgWarn(const char *msg, const int len) { dmesg("<4>", msg, len); }
void dmesgInfo(const char *msg, const int len) { dmesg("<6>", msg, len); }
void dmesgDebug(const char *msg, const int len) { dmesg("<7>", msg, len); }
```

**UPDATE** (Thanks @glglgl!)

A much simpler version could be like this:

```
void dmesg( const unsigned int tag, const char *msg)
{
    size_t msglen = sprintf(NULL, "<%u>%s", tag, msg);
    char buffer[msglen + 1];
    sprintf(buffer, "<%u>%s", tag, msg);
    // snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "<%u>%s", tag, msg);
    // would be safer, but here we make sure that everything works as it should.
    int fd_kmsg = open("/dev/kmsg", O_WRONLY);
    write(fd_kmsg, &buffer, msglen);
    close(fd_kmsg);
}
void dmesgWarn(const char *msg) { dmesg(4, msg); }
void dmesgInfo(const char *msg) { dmesg(6, msg); }
void dmesgDebug(const char *msg) { dmesg(7, msg); }
```

It now just takes strings, integrates them in a message to be written to that file and writes it.

Now that we talk about it, it can be even much easier:

```
void dmesg( const unsigned int tag, const char *msg)
{
    int fd_kmsg = open("/dev/kmsg", O_WRONLY);
    FILE * f_kmsg = fdopen(fd_kmsg, "w");
    fprintf(f_kmsg, "<%u>%s", tag, msg);
    fclose(f_kmsg); // closes the underlying fd_kmsg as well
}
void dmesgWarn(const char *msg) { dmesg(4, msg); }
void dmesgInfo(const char *msg) { dmesg(6, msg); }
void dmesgDebug(const char *msg) { dmesg(7, msg); }
```

Comment: `size_t taglen = strlen(tag); char buffer[taglen + len]; memcpy( &buffer[0], tag, taglen);
memcpy( &buffer[taglen], msg, len );` would do the trick as well.

Comment: Ok. I infer you are eliminating the need for the len argument?  You could directly suggest an edit in that case, if you were so inclined.

Comment: Not for the len argument (that could be done as well), but for the constant `TAG_LEN` and the constant `buffer[]` size.

Comment: @glglgl Please suggest an "edit" directly.  That is, you can modify my answer to improved it.  Note that I wrote this was a "lazy, but functional 5 minute workaround".  If you want to tweak this so it becomes a better answer, I certainly have no objection!

Comment: Ok, I just did so.

Comment: Cool.  Approved!  If you want fix it so no one has pass that `len` arg to call the function, that would be helpful as well.